# Jquery Dynamic 3d

Tags: jquery

```
for (var i = 1; i < 6; i++) {           
    $.post("random.php", {ajax: 'true'}, function(data) {
        var mus = data.split('-');       
        var pool = "<a href='"+mus[0]+"><img src='"+mus[1]+"'/></a>";
   -->    $(".rand" + i).html(pool); <--

    });     
}

<div id="list">
        <ul>
            <li class='rand1'> a</li>
            <li class='rand2'> a</li>
            <li class='rand3'> a</li>
            <li class='rand4'> a</li>
            <li class='rand5'> a</li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to load modify a list dynamically.. The html is not being set, any thoughts are much appreciated. :)

When I statically assign it    `$(".rand" + 1).html(pool);`
The html still won't change..

Thanks,

Still confused

```
      for (var j=0;j<5;j++) {          

    $.post("random.php",{ajax: 'true'}, function(data){

        mus = data.split('-');   
      mus[0] = mus[0].replace(/\r|\n/g, '');   
      mus[1] = mus[1].replace(/\r|\n/g, '');
      //  pool = "<a href='http://www.rain.org/~karpeles/"+mus[0]+"'><img src='http://www.rain.org/~karpeles/"+mus[1]+"'/></a>";
         $("#rand" + j).html("<img src='http://www.rain.org/karpeles/" + mus[1] +"'/>");

     });    

  }
```

The code works if I don't include the www ?

Peter

Comment: are you able to display the return "data"? please if possible add what the return object "data" looks like.

Comment: Also, are you aware you are missing a semi-colon after the post?

Comment: Yeah I can. The data formats just the way I want until assigning the LI tag

Comment: When I alert the text value of each LI comes up blank. By default I have <div id="list">
   <ul>
    <li class='rand1'> a</li>
    <li class='rand2'> a</li>
    <li class='rand3'> a</li>
    <li class='rand4'> a</li>
    <li class='rand5'> a</li>
   
   </ul>
  </div>

Comment: Suggestion.After you fix your script, try to make just one ajax call and in PHP call your random result for 6 times and return those six values.then in Javascript iterate over result an print what you need

Comment: I cleaned up the formatting for ease of reading, but first make sure you have that missing semi-colon as seen on line 7

Comment: The data comes back and is all set to go.. Just assigning it to a dynamic variable is getting screwy.. Any idea ?

Comment: fixed the semicolon. Still an issue with the assignment

Comment: @Peter - it's not working at all? it seems like it would with the `$(".rand" + 1).`...you're *sure* that's still broken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work!

```
   $.ajax({
    url: "random.php",
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    timeout: 30000,
    error: function(){
        return true;
    },
    success: function(data){ 
      mus.length=0;
      pool="";

      mus = data.split('-');   
      mus[0] = mus[0].replace(/\r|\n/g, '');   
      mus[1] = mus[1].replace(/\r|\n/g, '');
      var tmp= "http://www.rain.org/~karpeles/"+mus[1];

    $("#rand" + j).attr("src",tmp);
 //  alert(mus[1]);
   }
```

The first problem was my post function was firing too fast for my php to render the Curl statements and return.  So I switched to .ajax{ timeout:3000, success(data) and I got an answer every time. The next thing was with the plugin. 3d Tag Cloud doesn't render pictures!! so the text worked fine, but when I throw an img src it blanked out. GRR, so I looked into another plugin and now it's 100% ish :) just a simple project I was helping my brother with for school.

I really value everyone's support at stackoverflow. Thanks a bunch!
[link text](http://www.brightlightmerchants.com/karpeles/main)

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with the variable, then you can simply cut it out

```
$(".rand" + i).html("<a href='"+mus[0]+"><img src='"+mus[1]+"'/></a>");
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is past that. The values aren't setting

Comment: the data is splitting. currently I am investigating, Will update what I find out

Comment: .... !!! If I alert the variables, the assigning works.. Still not with the url concatenated though.. WTF :(